# How can I plot this 3d mesh with 3 columns of data

Tags: matlab

figure:

[image: figure]

I have 3 columns of data. I think **v** and **a** is a function of **f**

Is it possilble to plot a figure above?
Now I can just plot this data with scatter3()

sample of data

data:

[image: data]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`griddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) to interpolate between the points you have. For example, suppose your known points are:

```
a=[2 2 1 0 1 2.5];
v=[27 29 26 27 28 28];
f=[1.032 .938 .844 .375 .75 .75]/1000;
```

Then you can choose a density to sample over using [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) (here I chose 20 points in each range) and then interpolate like this:

```
n = 20;
[X, Y]=meshgrid(linspace(min(a),max(a),n),linspace(min(v),max(v),n));
Z=griddata(a,v,f,X,Y,'cubic');
mesh(X,Y,Z)
hold on; scatter3(a,v,f); % To compare the surface to the points
```

which creates:

[image: plot of surface]

Comment: Thank you so much. It  helps me a lot Mr.Teddy  :)

Comment: This work just fine with few point and I don't know why it didn't work with my 3k datapoint.
https://www.uppic.org/share-5BF8_58DA549C.html

Comment: There are two issues. The first warning comes because the points are inconsistent. For example, in your question, the last two points have the same accelerations and speed, but different fuel consumption. The warning is telling you that the average of those points will be used instead. The second error is because you have a Nan or infinity in your inputs. Look closely at your a,v, and f vectors to ensure they are all valid values.

Comment: It works now. Thanks :DD

One last question. Why the matrix is (100xn) ?. Why it's '100' ? 
Can I go >100 ?

Comment: oops! there was a misplaced parenthesis in the second `linspace` which caused the 20 to be missed. `linspace` defaults to 100. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Representing Data as a Surface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html)

Comment: I'm very very new to Matlab sir. I did search for many hours and still no hope with this. Thanks